# Android: add in data base (JSON)

Tags: android

I am currently developing an android application. When inserting informations of a form into the database, it posts , "Unfortunately .... has stopped," but in the table, a row is added. However my friend has the same code and it works. I have been two days searching for a solution... 
Waiting for a solution please :)

```
  package com.example.user.presentation;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Spinner;

    public class insc extends Activity {
        // Progress Dialog
                private ProgressDialog pDialog;

                JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
                EditText inputFullName;
                EditText inputLogin;
                EditText inputPassword;

                EditText inputdate;

                EditText inputMala;

                EditText inputMed;

                EditText inputfixe;

                EditText inputmobile;

                   Spinner sp;
                // url to create new product
                private static String url_create_product = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/create_user.php";

                // JSON Node names
                private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

                @Override
                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.insc);

              sp=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin);
                        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> ar = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.groupesanguin, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
                        ar.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
                        sp.setAdapter(ar);

                    // Edit Text
                    // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
                    inputFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                    inputLogin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
                    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
                    inputdate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
                    inputMala = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText8);
                    inputMed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText9);
                    inputfixe = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText10);
                    inputmobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText11);

                    // Create button
                    Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

                    // button click event
                    btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            // creating new product in background thread
                            new CreateNewProduct().execute();
                        }
                    });
                }

                /**
                 * Background Async Task to Create new product
                 * */
                class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

                    /**
                     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
                     * */
                    @Override
                    protected void onPreExecute() {
                        super.onPreExecute();
                        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(insc.this);
                        pDialog.setMessage("Ajout malade..");
                        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                        pDialog.show();
                    }

                    /**
                     * Creating product
                     * */
                    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {




                         String name = inputFullName.getText().toString();
                            String login = inputLogin.getText().toString();
                            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

                            String date = inputdate.getText().toString();
                             String gpesang=sp.getSelectedItem().toString();
                            String maladies = inputMala.getText().toString();
                            String medicaments = inputMed.getText().toString();
                            String fixe = inputfixe.getText().toString();
                            String mobile = inputmobile.getText().toString();




                        // Building Parameters
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", login));
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",password));
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gpesang",gpesang));
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date",date));
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("maladies",maladies));
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("medicaments",medicaments));
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fixe",fixe));
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobile",mobile));

                        // getting JSON Object
                        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                                "POST", params);

                        // check log cat fro response
                        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

                        // check for success tag
                        try {
                            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                            if (success == 1) {
                                // successfully created product
                                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Connect.class);
                                startActivity(i);

                                // closing this screen
                                finish();
                            } else {
                                // failed to create product
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        return null;
                    }

                    /**
                     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
                     * **/
                    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                        // dismiss the dialog once done
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                    }

                }
            }
```

Log:
[image]

Comment: Always post the full stack trace form logcat.

Comment: https://scontent-mad.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xtp1/v/t1.0-9/11051797_719012408196159_2555408036739594919_n.jpg?oh=7d9643307428315b949ae3e48d2f982e&oe=55B99ED8

Comment: probabely yes, but how does it work for my friend and the add to data base is successful, whay shall i do so? :)

Comment: Add a test `if(json != null){...}` before using it. You have a NPE when you try to call `json.toString()`

Comment: i still don't get any solution for that :(